# Assistant SDK on raspberry pi 3 throwing repeated location header errors

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk

Both an existing raspberry pi 3 assistant-sdk setup and a freshly created one are producing identical errors at all times idle or otherwise.  The lines below are repeating over and do not seem to be affected by the state of the assistant.  Replicates across multiple developer accounts, devices and projects.  Present with both the stock hotword example and modified scripts that worked previously.  All cases are library assistant and python 3 on raspberry pi 3 model B running raspbian stretch.

> [9780:9796:ERROR:assistant_ssdp_client.cc(210)] Failed to parse
>   header: LOCATION: about:blank
>
> [9780:9796:ERROR:assistant_ssdp_client.cc(76)] LOCATION header doesn't
>   contain a valid url

Comment: Question is unclear, try adding what you are trying to achieve. what you have tried and where you are stuck(i.e. issue)

Comment: Does the Assistant sample still work?

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it for me: pip3 install google-assistant-library==0.1.0

Comment: If I install google-assistant-library==0.1.0, I get the following error:



Testing the installed google assistant. Make a note of the generated Device-Id
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/env/bin/googlesamples-assistant-hotword", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/googlesamples/assistant/library/hotword.py", line 128, in main
    Assistant.__version_str__())
AttributeError: type object 'Assistant' has no attribute '__version_str__'